# Passing tables of different format to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, types, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to create a procedure which can take tables with different columns as argument?
For example, I have two types:

```
create type type1 as table ( id int, txtField nvarchar(20)); 
create type type2 as table ( id int, dateField date);
```

Now I want to create a procedure which can take **either type1 or type2** as argument. Is that possible? Something like this:

```
create procedure InsertRow (@dest as nvarchar(100), @data as "(type1 or type2)" )
```

Answer (score 2):

"No" is the simple answer. A parameter has the be defined, which means you must tell SQL Server what data type is it. You could, however, add both and then only use the one yiou need:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRow @Dest nvarchar(100), --I hope this isn't a dynamic object name
                 @type1 dbo.type1 READONLY,
                 @type2 dbo.type2 READONLY AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @type1) BEGIN
        --Do stuff
    END ELSE BEGIN
        --Do other stuff
    END;

...

END;
```

Or alternatively (and likely better), add both columns to your type, as it seems you need both:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.type3 AS TABLE (id int NOT NULL, txtField nvarchar(20) NULL, dateField date NULL);
```

And just insert into the column you need.

Comment: Adding that different types for the same parameter suggests an interface design flaw.